# Automated process to get content from URL's

Tags: php, python, json, automation, backend

I have a huge list of URL's from a client which I need to run through so i can get content from the pages. This content is in different tags within the page.

I am looking to create an automated service to do this which I can leave running to complete.
I want the automated process to load each page and get the content from particular html tags, then process some this content to ensure the html is correct.

If possible I want to generate one XML or JSON file, but I can settle for an XML or JSON file per page.

What is the best way to do this, preferably something I can run off a mac or a linux server.

The list of URL's are to an external site.

Is there something I can already use or an example somewhere which will help me.

Thanks

Comment: Python's [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is pretty good at parsing HTML. [urllib.request](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) is good at fetching things. Combine the two and you've got the tools you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect application of [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), IMHO.  Here is a [tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup/) on a similar process. It is certainly a headstart.

Answer (score 0):

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is an excellent framework for spidering and scraping.

I think you'll find it will involve a little more learning overhead based on the Requests + Beautiful Soup or LXML tutorial mentioned by tim-cook in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126063/263421). However if you're writing a lot of scraping / parsing logic it should guide toward a pretty well-factored (readiable, maintainable) codebase.

So, if it's a one-off run I'd go with Beautiful Soup + Requests. If it'll be re-used, extended and maintained over time then Scrapy would be my pick.